# Aluminum SMD Capacitor replacement question

Tags: surface-mount

I want to replace the caps on this mainboard but I'm not sure what to replace them with. I don't know enough about capacitance and am not sure where to turn for help.

Here's a picture. I don't know what the y2, x2, 2j and w4 represent. I'm assuming the next number is the microfarads and then the voltage. So on the one with the 2j for example... Don't know what 2j is, but does the 220 under it mean 220 microfarads? And then 4 volts? I'm finding all kinds of different kits but nothing with those exact numbers and letters. Can someone please help enlighten me on what I need to get to replace these caps? Thank you!!

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to replace those capacitors?  Unless you have a really good reason to think they are bad, I'd leave them alone.  Bad aluminum electrolytic capacitors would have bulged or split lids.  Those look fine.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

image source : https://www.microfarads.com/partners/jb/179-jck

i think X2 , y2 are just series or lot no it doesn't matter here

only capacitance and its voltage rating matters

Comment: Awesome Thank you very much! So I just go by the second and third numbers. So let's say the 'x2' one would be 330 microfarads and 4 volts?

Comment: yes you have to buy 330uf 4V capacitor

Comment: updated image for better understanding

Comment: And that's the one I just can't seem to find of course. Would you happen to know of any kits anywhere that might have all those capacitors in it?

Comment: you can find here https://www.mouser.in/Passive-Components/Capacitors/Aluminum-Electrolytic-Capacitors/Aluminum-Electrolytic-Capacitors-SMD/_/N-75hqx?P=1z0wrktZ1yqw5xo

Comment: The series is **important.**  Different series capacitors have different equivalent series resistance (ESR) ratings.  Since those capacitors appear to be in a switching power supply, the ESR can make a big difference.  Don't replace what ain't broke.

Comment: well we can not  help you to find any component for you , we can just clear your doubts

Comment: Wow, so how would I know what series to get?

Comment: i think you can choose any good enough ESR capacitor for this rating otherwise you have to find out the all rating of capacitor which is hard to find

Comment: Thank you Very much for all your help Jay! I really appreciate it!!

Comment: thanks & most welcome

Comment: No, you can't just choose any "good" ESR. Because, how is "good" defined? Like JRE also commented, the series is important because of the ESR (esp for elco's in a SMPS), and because of the life time.

Comment: Several people have asked **WHY** - answering them may make a large difference. || Some applications require caps with eg ESRs in a given range - neither too low ot too high. || Why do you THINK they are Al caps (they probably are, but ...)